# Projection issue with vector layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector

I'm new to using QGIS. I seem to have the issue that a vector layer I've imported into QGIS 3.26.3 is incorrectly projected into the project as it isn't where it should be. It seems that the layers features are all too far to the left compared to where they should be. Some features can be moved manually using the move feature edit tool but for other features this would not work, so I'm looking for a way in which I can shift the layer on the whole to the left by whatever distance the objects are ajar. On the image below the yellow layer is the current projection of the layer and the blue layer represents where the various parts should be (these have just been moved manually using the move feature tool). All the layers within the project are in the CRS ESPG: 27700 - OSGB36 / British National Grid.

[image]

Comment: Step 1: compare a single (small) polygon from each layer and check if the coordinates are the same in each case, if they are they you have selected a different transform for the two layers and this expected. If they are different then some one further back in the production chain has chosen a different transform and you need to ask them to fix it.

Comment: have you looked up the EPSG for your features (right click > properties > information) and made sure that the data has the same EPSG assigned (properties > source)? Also have you tried to set the EPSG  of your entire project to this (bottom-right corner)? Also have a look here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/working_with_projections.html

Comment: @IanTurton I have compared the coordinates of same points on the yellow polygon and where it should be on the project and found the X is off by ~95 and Y ~28. I am confident that this is the same for all the features of the layer. Do you have any suggestions as to what to do with this?

Comment: Ask whomever prepared the data to tell you which transform they used so you can undo it and reproject it to match the blue one

Answer (score 0):

So your question is: "**I'm looking for a way in which I can shift the layer on the whole to the left by whatever distance the objects are ajar**"

Let's say you picked P1, P1', P2 and P2'.
[image]

P1  has the Coordinates E1 & N1
P1' has the Coordinates E1' & N1
P2  has the Coordinates E2 & N2
P2' has the Coordinates E2' & N2

If [(E1' - E1)² - (N1' - N1)²]^(1/2) = [(E2' - E2)² - (N2' - N2)²],

That means you just need to perform a simple translation, using the dE and dN parameters. It can be calculated by using the formula below:

For Easting (X): E1' - E1
For Northing (Y): N1' - N1

If they are not equal, there are other possibilities:

1. The data needs to be scaled.
2. The data needs to be rotated.
3. The data needs to be both rotated and scaled.

Considering the data needs only to be shifted, use the "Translate tool", and input the parameters accordingly.